# Load cell selectively in TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cell

I need to return cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: only when some condition is true,for example:

```
if (condition == true)
return nil;
else
return cell;
```

Returning nil gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a little more to conditionally have a cell in a UITableView.

Let's assume you have 3 cells, and the first one is conditional.  The first thing you need to do make your table have either 2 or 3 cells based on this condition:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(condition) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Next you can return the actual cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(condition) {
        if(indexPath.row == 0) {
            //create and return conditional cell
        } else {
            //create and return normal cell
        }
    } else {
        //create and return normal cell
    }
}
```

And voila!

PS: (This is assuming everything is done in a single section. If you need to break that out into multiple sections we can get into that as well).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you cannot have blank spaces in your `UITableView`, that is not allowed, you must at least return an empty cell. What are you trying to do?

The error presents when the `TableView` tries to retrieve the next cell and gets nil, it has to get the next cell no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you are intending to do here could you not do perform the conditional test before making a call to tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

EG

```
if( someCondition )
{
    [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
}
```

Or if your out come is to only display the table cells that meet a certain condition the I suggest you create a function that would copy those elements from your tableview data into an NSArray that you would use to display the desired/conditional table data.

IE

```
-(void)composeVisibleTableData
{
    [m_visibleTableData removeAllObjects];
    for( NSObject* dataObject in m_tableDataArray )
    {
       if( someCondition )//dataObject meetsCondition
       {
           m_visibleTableData addObject:dataObject];
       }
    }

}
```

Then in your UITableDelegate functions for numberOfRowsInSection: and tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: reference m_visibleTableData as the UITableView Data Source.

Answer (score 0):

You should check condition when Cell's datasource is set :)

and Filter your data with condition.