# How to create UITableView cells based on a condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Suppose i have eight cells in my `UITableView` but i want to display only those cells that meet a specific condition. I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654866/load-cell-selectively-in-tableview) and have implemented my `numberOfRowsInSection` as:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
int i = 0;
for (A2OActivityCounter *ac in activityCounters) {
    if(ac.startDate != nil) {
        i++;
    }
}
if (i == 0) {
    return 1;
   }
return i;
}
```

So this will return exactly the number of cells that meet the criteria and the once that i want in my tableview. I want to know how do I implement this in my tableview. For example, there are five out of eight cells that meet the criteria, so number of rows returned will be five. But i only want those five cells to be displayed and no blank cell in between those cells. So if the cells are like:

`A - satisfies the condition
B - satisfies the condition
C - **does not** satisfies the condition
D - satisfies the condition
E - **does not** satisfies the condition
F - satisfies the condition
G - **does not** satisfies the condition
H - satisfies the condition`

As you might have guessed i want only A, B, D, F and H in my table, with no empty cells in between them. If can't just use `if (activityCounter.startDate != nil)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, because what do i return if the condition isn't `true`, the method requires that i return `(UITableViewCell *)`, so i can;t even return `nil`.
Can someone help me with this, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking about the problem the wrong way. You have a set of data `activityCounters`, and a subset of that data that you want to be displayed. So, you should have another instance variable, like `displayedActivityCounters`, which is the filtered list of content that is currently actually being displayed.

Now, all of your table methods use only `displayedActivityCounters`.

When you change your filtering criteria you generate a new version of `displayedActivityCounters` from `activityCounters` and reload the table.

Answer (score 1):

Why not enumerate over the array of activityCounters in a method and reload the UITableView? For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredActivityCounters;

- (void)setupContent {

self.filteredActivityCounters = [NSMutableArray array];

for (A2OActivityCounter *ac in activityCounters) {
    if(ac.startDate != nil) {
        [self.filteredActivityCounters addObject:ac];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return self.filteredActivityCounters.count;
}
```

Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method can just pull directly from this filtered array:

```
A2OActivityCounter *ac = self.filteredActivityCounters[indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a cell by implementing this tableview delegate method like below:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CGFloat height = 44.0;//suupose your default hieght is 44.0

    if (indexPath.row== cell c's row || indexPath.row== cell E's row  || indexPath.row== cell G's row) {
        height = 0.0;
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: You can use a default cell for not satisfy condition and hide it from above code